# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe with SMTP

Tags: java, jboss, smtp, ejb, jakarta-mail

I got strange behavior when my application tries to send an email.

```
20:59:08,926 ERROR [release.com.mycompany.mail.GenericMail] (EJB default - 5) [MY_EJB INBOUND] Sending message failed!: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2106) [mail-1.4.4-redhat-2.jar:1.4.4-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2093) [mail-1.4.4-redhat-2.jar:1.4.4-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1184) [mail-1.4.4-redhat-2.jar:1.4.4-redhat-2]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:197) [mail-1.4.4-redhat-2.jar:1.4.4-redhat-2]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) [mail-1.4.4-redhat-2.jar:1.4.4-redhat-2]
    at com.mycompany.MailUtils.sendMail(MailUtils.java:258) [classes:]
```

Before this exception some timeout exception has been thrown:

```
    20:57:50,291 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 9) [ ] JBAS014122: Error during
retrying timeout for timer: [id=6be904b5-c1ef-4f0e-a277-d4c9f93e21b3 timedObjectId=SOME_EJB 
auto-timer?:false persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@99fdab1 initialExpiration=/* date */ 00:00:00 UTC 2015 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=/* other date */ 21:00:00 UTC 2015 
timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: JBAS014373: 
EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation@66668127 - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS
```

To be honest i don't know whats happened. I got these kind of exception for 5 hours. 
I want to know whats happened and be able to avoid exceptions in future.

**UPDATE 1**

`SOME_EJB` is an ejb with works with timerService. Runs every 3 minutes, when the conditions are met sends an email.

My only idea is that there was some network/database issue and it caused that single execution of task took more than 3 minutes.

`MailUtils` is a `@Stateless` ejb

Answer (score 0):

Is the mail sent or not?

It looks like JavaMail is closing the connection to the mail server when the exception occurs.  If a previous error caused the server to drop the connection immediately, JavaMail may be getting this exception while trying to send the SMTP BYE command before closing the connection.

Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see what error the server might have reported before this exception occurs.

Comment: Mail has not been sent. Unfortunately turn on debug is not solution for me because i don't know how to reproduce this behavior. Please also see update to my post.

Comment: You can use Session.setDebugOut to redirect the debug output to a file, then throw the file away on success and save it for later debugging on failure.  Without more details, all you can assume is that the server or the network failed and you need to retry the operation.